# Sharepoint "Company administrator" - person has left, what now?

Tags: administration

So the user who originaly had the account is no longer around. The user is even deleted.

How do I edit the account Sharepoint considers "company administrator"?

I have another account that's Global administator, but that doesnt count does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Default-SharePoint-Groups-in-SharePoint-Online-13bb2b6b-dd8c-447e-b71b-0e4bb9efe1d3#__toc339377366)

> **Company Administrators**    Any user who is a Global admin on Office 365 is a member of the Company Administrator group. By default, the Office 365 Company Administrators group is added into the SharePoint Owners group. In addition, the Company Administrators group is added to the list of Site Collection administrators. This group has a permission level of Full Control.

Just go to your `global Admin Portal > Users > Active Users` You can see all active users. Select one and Click `Edit User Roles` on the right. There you can make him/her a limited admin or a  Global Admin